# CSS: Position my text block to the right (fully) of my icon (::before)

Tags: html, css

I currently work on some alert messages for my site and I would like to position a left icon that will be placed in my alert message:

```css
.alert {
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
}
.alert p::before {
  content: "";
  background: red; /* Some icon */
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.alert.success {
  background-color: rgb(221, 255, 181);
  color: rgb(139, 195, 74);
}
```

```html
<div class="alert success">
  <p>Hae duae provinciae bello quondam piratico catervis mixtae praedonum a Servilio pro consule missae sub iugum factae sunt vectigales. et hae quidem regiones velut in prominenti terrarum lingua positae ob orbe eoo monte Amano disparantur. Hae duae provinciae
    bello quondam piratico catervis mixtae praedonum a Servilio pro consule missae sub iugum factae sunt vectigales. et hae quidem regiones velut in prominenti terrarum lingua positae ob orbe eoo monte Amano disparantur.</p>
</div>
```

[image]

As you can see, my icon is well placed, but my text is not. I would like that the text is placed fully to the right.

[image]

Comment: "text is placed fully to the right" means what? could you please elaborate..

Comment: I would like the text does not go below the icon and it is always positioned to the right of the icon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the width of the pseudo-element is known, you can add some `pading-left` to the container, and use absolute positioning for the icon:

```css
.alert p {
  position: relative; /* Become containing block of abspos children */
  padding-left: 25px; /* Push the text a 25px to the right */
}
.alert p::before {
  position: absolute; /* Take it out-of-flow */
  left: 0;            /* Place it at the left of its containing block */
}
```

```css
.alert {
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
}
.alert p {
  padding-left: 25px;
  position: relative;
}
.alert p::before {
  content: "";
  background: red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
.alert.success {
  background-color: rgb(221, 255, 181);
  color: rgb(139, 195, 74);
}
```

```html
<div class="alert success">
  <p>Hae duae provinciae bello quondam piratico catervis mixtae praedonum a Servilio pro consule missae sub iugum factae sunt vectigales. et hae quidem regiones velut in prominenti terrarum lingua positae ob orbe eoo monte Amano disparantur. Hae duae provinciae
    bello quondam piratico catervis mixtae praedonum a Servilio pro consule missae sub iugum factae sunt vectigales. et hae quidem regiones velut in prominenti terrarum lingua positae ob orbe eoo monte Amano disparantur.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using `position: absolute` on the generated content (the `::before` pseudo-element) and defining a `left-margin` for the `<p>` element equal to the width of that pseudo-element and any required gutter between the pseudo-element and the element itself:

```
.alert p {
  /* giving space for the pseudo-element
     to occupy: */
  margin-left: 25px;

  /* setting a non-static position, so
     the pseudo-element will be positioned
     in relation to this element, rather
     than any ancestor elements: */
  position: relative;
}

.alert p::before {

  /* without an absolute URL to link
     to your actual image, I used a
     substitute character instead: */
  content: "✓";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;

  /* positioning the element absolutely
     with reference to its parent: */
  position: absolute;

  /* positioning the element's right
     side 100% away from its parents'
     right side: */
  right: 100%;
}
/* All unlisted CSS remains the same */
```

```css
.alert {
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
}

.alert p {
  margin-left: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

.alert p::before {
  content: "✓";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
}

.alert.success {
  background-color: rgb(221, 255, 181);
  color: rgb(139, 195, 74);
}
```

```html
<div class="alert success">
  <p>Hae duae provinciae bello quondam piratico catervis mixtae praedonum a Servilio pro consule missae sub iugum factae sunt vectigales. et hae quidem regiones velut in prominenti terrarum lingua positae ob orbe eoo monte Amano disparantur. Hae duae provinciae
    bello quondam piratico catervis mixtae praedonum a Servilio pro consule missae sub iugum factae sunt vectigales. et hae quidem regiones velut in prominenti terrarum lingua positae ob orbe eoo monte Amano disparantur.</p>
</div>
```

To fully utilise the gutter spacing, it's possible in some browsers to use the calc() function of CSS, which can perform mathematical operations on valid CSS units/lengths when positioning the pseudo-element, for example:

```
right: calc(100% + 5px);
```

```css
.alert {
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
}

.alert p {
  margin-left: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

.alert p::before {
  content: "✓";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  right: calc(100% + 5px);
}

.alert.success {
  background-color: rgb(221, 255, 181);
  color: rgb(139, 195, 74);
}
```

```html
<div class="alert success">
  <p>Hae duae provinciae bello quondam piratico catervis mixtae praedonum a Servilio pro consule missae sub iugum factae sunt vectigales. et hae quidem regiones velut in prominenti terrarum lingua positae ob orbe eoo monte Amano disparantur. Hae duae provinciae
    bello quondam piratico catervis mixtae praedonum a Servilio pro consule missae sub iugum factae sunt vectigales. et hae quidem regiones velut in prominenti terrarum lingua positae ob orbe eoo monte Amano disparantur.</p>
</div>
```

In the above snippet I've kept the original rule, in order that browsers that don't/can't implement `calc()` can still appropriately position the element despite not placing it entirely correctly.